# Insert block of color into text file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vi

The following line of code appears in a python source file. It appears exactly like this when the file is opened up in VS Code and in vi (as well as this text edit block). When I cat the file, the green square is replaced by several non-ascii characters. My question is how does one create a line of text with a swatch of some arbitrary color?

```
   'correct_place': '',
```

Comment: don't know if this is a solution, but you might have to change the encoding of the cat command to match? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78776/characters-encodings-supported-by-more-cat-and-less

Comment: I don't care so much that cat isn't displaying the color swatch. What I want to know is how it got entered into the file, via vi or code, in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

("Large Green Square") is actually an emoji. Every emoji has a unicode number. The unicode number for  is `U+1F7E9`.

You can open a file in VSCode, copy the emoji above and paste it in that file (using the regular copy and paste commands on your computer, like command+C command+V).

You can also use the `echo` command in a Linux terminal to write this emoji into a file by using 's unicode number, for example:
$ `echo -e '\U0001F7E9' >> sizzzzlerz.txt`
$ `cat sizzzzlerz.txt`